# Do we have Power Tools for CMS in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, powertools

I found a big list of power tools published on [sdltridionworld.com](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx) for Tridion CMS. Each tool description is impressive and can help to fix lot of pain-points for daily cms tasks.

Are these power tools available for Tridion 2013 SP1. if yes do we have any installation zip available for same.

I am looking for below tool specifically at this moment to solve my current problem:

**Component Synchronizer:** Tool to make sure all components are in sync with their schemas

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation from the community it is no longer in active development. You can still get it from this link and more info on the same here http://tridioncommunity.github.io/tridion-powertools/

Answer (score 2):

Install the below Alchemy extension which will do the task for you:

https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Component-Synchronizer

Answer (score 2):

In SDL Tridion 2013 the use-case for an external component synchronizer became less compelling with the introduction of a core service API to take care of this task. See the documentation [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2B44D2F8-65E9-40DD-8408-DF1537BE50F5). I imagine this is how it's done in the Alchemy plugin, although it's clearly a matter of personal preference whether you feel the need for a graphical user interface.